# Matching an input pattern beginning of script

Tags: javascript, html, checkvalidity

I'm trying to match only GitHub URLs with the following input tag:

```
<input type="url" id="repoUrl" title="Must be a full URL to a GitHub repository" pattern="^https:\/\/github\.com\/" required>
```

In regex101 this exact pattern is matching all strings that start with "https://github.com" which is what I want, but the problem is that when I call the `checkValidity()` method on that input, it only says it's valid if the input is *only* "https://github.com".

**What do I need to change to make this regex work how it works in regex101?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `.*` in the end of a pattern

```
pattern="^https:\/\/github\.com\/.*"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!! I will accept the answer as soon as I can!